# Check if "Break comments into pages" is selected

Tags: pagination

I am working with a `paginate_comments_links()` function and the thing is that I have customized it slightly (wrapped with a div), I need to check if check box "Break comments into pages..." in WP admin -> Settings -> Discussion Settings -> Other comment settings was checked. So the question is how would I grab the results? The issue is that if it is not checked `paginate_comments_links()` will not do anything, but my div will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check is done with `get_option('page_comments')`.

But you could use another solution:

```
$prev = get_previous_comments_link();
$next = get_next_comments_link();

if ( '' !== $prev . $next )
    echo "<div>$prev $next</div>";
```

Comment: Awesome, `get_option('page_comments')` exactly what I was looking for.